# Organise element in a array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

i'm searching a smart way to reoganise an array by a element inside it:
In entry i've got:

```
[{"name": "brevet",
"country": "fr"
},{
"name": "bac",
"country": "fr"
},{
"name": "des",
"country": "ca"
},{
"name": "dep",
"country": "ca"
}{
"name": "other",,
"country": "other"}]
```

I want to reorganize my array by country to have this in my output:

```
[{
    "name": "fr",
    "degrees": [
    {
        "name": "brevet",
        "country": "fr"
    },{
        "name": "bac",
        "country": "fr"
    }]
},{
    "name": "ca",
    "degrees": [{
        "name": "des",
        "country": "ca"
    },{
        "name": "dep",
        "country": "ca"
    }]
},{
    "name": "other",
    "degrees": [{
        "name": "other",
        "country": "other"
    }]
}]
```

For this i write a dirty function, but it seems to me there is a better way but i don't see how. If someone can ligth my brain in a better way to do this i'll be helpfull

```
private organizeDegrees(degrees: Array<SubscriptionFieldInterface>) {
let degreesByCountry = new Array();
let storeIndex = new Array();
degrees.map(degree => {
  let index = null;
  storeIndex.find((element, idx) => {
    if (element === degree.country) {
      index = idx;
      return true;
    }
  });
  if (index === null) {
    index = degreesByCountry.length;
    let newEntry = {
      'name': degree.country,
      'degrees': new Array()
    };
    storeIndex.push(degree.country);
    degreesByCountry.push(newEntry);
  }
  degreesByCountry[index].degrees.push(degree);
});
return degreesByCountry;
}
```

thank's

Comment: This is less "sort by" and more "group by".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group the array and map the object using `Object.keys`:

```
var groupBy = function(xs, key) {
  return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    return rv;
  }, {});
};

var grouped = groupBy(array, "country");

var mappedArray = Object.keys(grouped).map(key => ( {name: key, degrees: grouped [key]} ));
```

Comment: The mapping is easier with `Object.values`

Comment: `Object.values` is very new and has very limited support.

Comment: I thank's for this quick response. I use the exemple with Object.keys because with my version of Typescript Object.value don't work. But i'm glad to ask the question because you gives me usefull responses and now i reconsider all my scripts.

Answer (score 0):

And one more way:

```
arr = [ /* your array */ ];

arr = Object.values(arr.reduce((ac, el) => {
    if(!ac[el.country]) ac[el.country] = {"name": el.country, "degrees": []}

    ac[el.country].degrees.push(el);

    return ac
}, {}))

console.log(arr) // formated
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, which also handles 'id' => '@id' mapping:

```js
const a = [{"name":"brevet","country":"fr"},{"name":"bac","country":"fr"},{"id":73,"name":"des","country":"ca"},{"name":"dep","country":"ca"},{"name":"other","country":"other"}];

const r = [...new Set(a.map(({country}) => country))] // list of unique country names
  .map(c => Object.assign({name: c}, // for each country
    {degrees: a.filter(x => x.country === c).map(y => Object.keys(y).includes('id') // handle 'id' => '@id' mutation
      ? {'@id': "/subscription_fields/" + y.id, name: y.name, country: y.country}
      : y)
    }))

console.log(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is purely ES6, and quite terse, but possibly less readable. Also, it doesn't add the "@id": "/subscription_fields/83", which could be added as a post process:

```
const groupByKey = (arr, key) => [...arr.reduce((acc, deg) =>
  acc.set(deg[key],  {name: deg[key], degrees: [ ...(acc.get(deg[key]) || {degrees: []}).degrees, deg]})
, new Map()).values()];

console.log(groupByKey(degrees, 'country'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash table and collect all values in an object. For getting the result array, you need to push the object only once.

```js
var data = [{ name: "brevet", country: "fr" }, { name: "bac", country: "fr" }, { id: 73, name: "des", country: "ca" }, { name: "dep", country: "ca" }, { name: "other", country: "other" }],
    result = data.reduce(function (hash) {
        return function (r, a) {
            if (!hash[a.country]) {
                hash[a.country] = { name: a.country, degrees: [] };
                r.push(hash[a.country]);
            }
            hash[a.country].degrees.push({ name: a.name, country: a.country });
            return r;
        };
    }(Object.create(null)), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```